# How to create json response

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, google-maps

I am developing an android app by using google map v2, at server end i am using php and mysql database. In database there are already many location coordinates in terms of latitudes and longitudes are stored, so what i want is when user turn On the app the backgroud service fetch all these latitudes and longitudes from database through server and display on the map, but i am stuck at php end. Suppose this is my database data

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|  uid    |  lat    | long    |  loc   |
+---------+---------+------- -+--------+
| 1       |Value1 A1|Value2 A1|    A   |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| 2       |Value1 B2|Value2 B2|    B   |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| 3       |Value1 C3|Value2 C3|    C   |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| 4       |Value1 D4|Value2 D4|    D   |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

This query can give me data row wise `$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid, lat, long, loc FROM table")` but how can i store this data in some array sequence wise so when encode it in json it will generate similar response like this

```
    [
    {
    "uid": "1": [
            {
                "lat": "Value1_A1",
                "lon": "Value2_A1"
                "loc": "A"
            }

        ]
    },
    {
    "uid": "2": [
            {
                "lat": "Value1_B2",
                "lon": "Value2_B2"
                "loc": "B"
            }

        ]
    },
{
    "uid": "3": [
            {
                "lat": "Value1_C3",
                "lon": "Value2_C3"
                "loc": "C"
            }

        ]
    },
{
    "uid": "4": [
            {
                "lat": "Value1_D4",
                "lon": "Value2_D4"
                "loc": "D"
            }

        ]
    },
    and so on...............
]
```

Please help me as i am serching for the solution from last two days but unable to find any reasonable solution.

Comment: go through google..search for tutorial.. that will help you more...

Comment: Your sample json is invalid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try mysql_fetch_assoc:

```
$json = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[$row['uid']] = array(
       'lat' => $row['lat'],
       'lon' => $row['lon'],
       'loc' => $row['loc']
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

You should use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead of mysql_.

Comment: How to do the reverse?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid, lat, long, loc FROM table")
    $user = array();
$i=0;
  foreach($result as $key => $val){
$mess[$i][uid]=$val[uid];
$mess[$i][uid]=$val[lat];
$mess[$i][uid]=$val[long];
$i++;
}

$user=$mess;
echo json_encode($user);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your $results and build it out to an array then pass it through the json_encode as follows..

```
json_encode($array);
```

You would do this in php to output json

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php