# how to work with php return to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, web

I have a question on how to work with a `php` return in jquery with ajax.

i have html fields:

```
<input type='text' id='name'>
<input type='text' id='color'>
<input type='text' id='material'>
```

I am sending the value of it to php to be checked if it exists

in php I have if's that write error number to an array $errors:

```
if($_POST['name'] == "") { $errors[] = "1"; }

if($_POST['name'] == "Name") { $errors[] = "2"; }
```

at the end php returns the array with errors:

```
foreach($errors AS $error) {
                echo $error";
            }
```

Now I would like to make changes to css when I get the errors. Something like this

```
success: function(html){
    if(html.$errors.1) {do this}  //this is not correct js I know, but please understand me, I am just learning

          if(html.$errors.2) {do this}
                }
```

The problem is I have no idea how to access the errors;
html returns something like this: 123
if second field for example is not with an error, the return is: 13

Could you guys help me out with this situation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Search how you can create a json in php that will contain the error flags and then echo it to your js file

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441433/how-to-create-json-response

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
<input type='text' id='name'>
<span id="name_err" style="display:none;">Please enter name</span>

<input type='text' id='color'> 
<span id="color_err" style="display:none;">Please enter color</span>

<input type='text' id='material'>
<span id="material_err" style="display:none;">Please enter material</span>
```

in Javascript, write like this

```
if(html.$errors.2)
{
document.getElementById("color").style.display = "block"; 
}
 if(html.$errors.1)
{
document.getElementById("name").style.display = "block"; 
}
 if(html.$errors.3)
{
document.getElementById("material").style.display = "block"; 
}
```